# list of public functions/classes with their corresponded header files

Tags: c++, stl

I tried to find a place where I can find ready to copy list of all functions and classes available in each stl header file.

Looking through /usr/include/c++ is not so convenient as I expected.

Google very often shows
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/
which is not so convenient to copy and paste.

Does anyone knows a good place to look?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
This is for an "auto stl header" plugin. So I don't need an examples. Just correspondence of each std::xxx to <yyy>.

**For Vim users and those who might be interested**
Using half given links and the std header files I've created auto std include vim plugin. I can't choose right one answer by now. But the method with which I can receive such kind of information more automatically is still considering by me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but if you need a reference and a list of functions from the headers, then maybe [dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/) manuals. If you want examples then try [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/CatalogCpp.htm). If you want an absolute and the true reference then go to the ISO standard.

I forgot to mention [SGI STL programmers guide](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/)...

Answer (score 1):

One site that I've always found useful for STL is [SGI's STL page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).

Have a look in the Index page and the Index by Category page.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

SGI has the most comprehensive documentation of the STL (except streams)

A list of of most things is here organised by category:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html

A Full list is here:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_index.html

I just use this page:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl

Answer (score 0):

Why not run your own implementation's headers through a tool like Doxygen?

Comment: Doxygen won't know which classes and functions are just for implementation and are not supposed to be used explicitly.

Comment: Well then, it sounds like what you need is a copy of the ISO C++ Standard. It's the only official list of such things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everyone's STL may not be exactly ISO standard, but the GCC doxygen output might fit your needs nevertheless. Start here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/

Browsing down through the output, I cannot find any single page that lists all classes *and* their functions together, but maybe you could write a little wget-based script to aggregate it in the format that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I like the SGI docs.The [categorized index](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_index_cat.html) seems like it is close to what you want in a list. The [main page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/index.html).